# bash script to monitor a process's memory usage and kill it

Tags: bash, unix, memory-management

I'm looking for a bash script that allows me to start a process in background, monitor its memory consumption every 10 minutes for example, and if it exceeds a certain value kill it.

EDIT 
I can correctly take the right pid of the process I would like to kill, but the sudo kill "$ FIRST" command does not seem to work and upon exiting the script, typing htop on the console, the process is still alive.
Also if I type sudo kill #pid directly on the console this command works and kills the process

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo python3 main.py &
sleep 5
pidlist=$(pidof python3 main.py)
echo "$pidlist"
read FIRST __ <<< "$pidlist"
echo "$FIRST"
mem=$(ps -p "$FIRST" -o %mem)
echo "$mem"
set -- $mem
memory="$2"
while true;
do
  sleep 2
  echo "$memory"
  if (( $(echo "${memory} > 20.0" | bc) )); then
    echo "killing process"
    sudo kill "$FIRST"
    break
  fi
  sleep 2
done
```

with set -x, the console also prints the part relating to the start of the process but at the end of the script this printed part no longer appears on the console

```
+ mem='%MEM
 25.5'
+ echo '%MEM
 25.5'
%MEM
 25.5
+ set -- %MEM 25.5
+ memory=25.5
+ true
+ sleep 2
+ echo 25.5
25.5
++ bc
++ echo '25.5 > 20.0'
+ ((  1  ))
+ echo 'killing process'
killing process
+ sudo kill 2247
+ break
```

Comment: Put something inside the conditional. The `if` syntax needs to have a body.

Comment: yes actually there is something inside if, sorry I correct the post

Comment: Good. Now compare against `20`, not `20.0`

Comment: In any case, your current code no longer throws the error you claim.

Comment: @Poshi no the code continues to give the same error. I'm running the code on an ec2 instance on aws I don't know if it can help

Comment: Have you considered these answers? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process

Comment: I cannot see any syntax error in your code. Are you sure that you get this error while running THIS code?

Comment: @Poshi yes it is

Comment: This code snippet don't have any syntax error. Maybe you are not closing the loop properly.

Comment: float comparison is not supported in bash. Try: `if [ "$memory" -gt "20" ]`

Comment: @DigvijayS I'm using this code for the moment without the while loop and I get always this error and I don't know why, even with "20"

Comment: @Poshi ok my script lines seem to be terminated with DOS line terminators <CR> = \r = 0x0D = ^M and it was for this reason that it did not work. I corrected the code and now I have another problem, post modified

Comment: The `killing process` message is printed? Try to run the script with `set -x` so you can see what is exactly executed.

Comment: @Poshi yes killing process message is printed. Sorry I'm new to bash programming, you mean to start the script in this way? `bash ./script.sh set -x` What should appear on the console?

Comment: Just put `set -x` inside your script, close to the beginning. For each subsequent line, you will see the interpreted command as understood by `bash`, with all the variable expansions, word splittings... done.

Comment: @Poshi post edited. 2247 is the process pid but is not actually killed. Also I'm running the script inside screen I don't know if it can help

Comment: Are you saying that if you copy-paste the kill command from the `set -x` output into your shell (importantly, using the same pid that the script outputs and not looking it up yourself), then the process dies? If not, use a stronger signal

Comment: @thatotherguy yes if I type sudo kill 2247 (same process number) directly on the console the process dies

Comment: Does the script fail to kill it even if you use `sudo kill -9 "$FIRST"`?

Comment: @thatotherguy this seems to work thanks

Comment: @james Then I'm guessing that the process tried to handle the `SIGTERM` the first time, takes too long or got stuck, and so your manual `kill` later interrupted it. The best practice is to `kill -TERM` (aka `kill`) first, wait some suitable number of seconds to give it a chance to shut down properly, then `-KILL` (aka `-9`) if it still hasn't died